# jq filter to ignore values in select statement based on array values

Tags: json, jq

Given the following JSON input :

```
{
  "hostname": "server1.domain.name\nserver2.domain.name\n*.gtld.net",
  "protocol": "TCP",
  "port": "8080\n8443\n9500-9510",
  "component": "Component1",
  "hostingLocation": "DC1"
}
```

I would like to obtain the following JSON output :

```
{
  "hostname": [
    "server1.domain.name",
    "server2.domain.name",
    "*.gtld.net"
  ],
  "protocol": "TCP",
  "port": [
    "8080-8080",
    "8443-8443",
    "9500-9510"
  ],
  "component": "Component1",
  "hostingLocation": "DC1"
}
```

Considering :

1. That the individual values in the `port` array may, or may not, be separated by a `-` character (I have no control over this).
2. That if an individual value in the `port` array does not contain the `-` separator, I then need to add it and then repeat the array value after the `-` separator. For example, `8080` becomes `8080-8080`, `8443` becomes `8443-8443` and so forth.
3. And finally, that if a value in the `port` array is already of the format `value-value`, I should simply leave it unmodified.

I've been banging my head against this filter all afternoon, after reading many examples both here and in the official `jq` online documentation. I simply can't figure out how to accomodate consideration #3 above.

The filter I have now :

`{hostname: .hostname | split("\n"), protocol: .protocol, port: .port | split("\n") | map(select(. | contains("-") | not)+"-"+.), component: .component, hostingLocation: .hostingLocation}`

Yields the following output JSON :

```
{
  "hostname": [
    "server1.domain.name",
    "server2.domain.name",
    "*.gtld.net"
  ],
  "protocol": "TCP",
  "port": [
    "8080-8080",
    "8443-8443"
  ],
  "component": "Component1",
  "hostingLocation": "DC1"
}
```

As you can see above, I subsequently lose the `9500-9510` value as it already contains the `-` string which my filter weeds out.

If my logic does not fail me, I would need to stick an `if` statement within my `select` statement to conditionally only send array values that do not contain the string `-` to my select statement but leave array values that do contain the separator untouched. However, I cannot seem to figure this last piece out.

I will happily accept any alternative filter that yields the desired output, however I am also really keen on understanding where my logics fails in the above filter.

Thanks in advance to anyone spending their valuable time helping me out!

/Joel

Answer (score 0):

First, we split the hostname string by a newline character (`.hostname /= "\n"`) and do the same with the port string (`.port /= "\n"`). Actually, we can combine these identical operations into one: `(.hostname, .port) /= "\n"`

Next, for every element of the port array (`.port[]`) we split by any non-digit character (`split("[^\\d]";"g")`) resulting in an array of digit-only strings, from which we take the first element (`.[0]`), then a dash sign, and finally either the second element, if present, otherwise the first one again (`.[1]//.[0]`)

With your input in a file called input.json, the following should convert it into the desired format:

```
jq '

  (.hostname, .port) /= "\n" |
  .port[] |= (split("[^\\d]";"g") | "\(.[0])-\(.[1]//.[0])")

' input.json
```

Regarding your considerations:

1. As we split at any non-digit character, it makes no difference what other character separates the values of a port range. If more than one character could separate them (e.g. an arrow `->` or with spaces before and after the dash sign `-`), simply replace the regex `[^\\d]` with `[^\\d]+` for capturing more than one non-digit character.
2. and 3. We always produce a range by including a dash sign and a second value, which depending on the presence of a second item may be either that or the first one again.

Regarding your approach:

Inside `map` you used `select` which evaluates to `empty` if the condition (`contains("-") | not`) is not met. As `"9500-9510"` does indeed contain a dash sign, it didn't survive. An `if` statement *inside* the `select` statement wouldn't help because even if `select` doesn't evaluate to `empty` it still doesn't modify anything, it just reproduces its input unchanged. Therefore, if `select` is letting through both cases (containing and not containing dash signs) it becomes useless. You could, however, work with an `if` statement *outside* of the `select` statement, but I considered the above solution as a simpler approach.